# Is “either” or “too” better in "It's a no-go today ____"?

Tags: difference, adverb-placement

In this example, which of the appended words sound more natural:

> It’s a no-go today either

> It’s a no-go today too

Does a comma after “today” change anything?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Although the meaning of 'no-go' is negative, the sentence - *It's a [... kind of] day* is positive, so you *must* use 'too'.

Compare *We're not going to have a fine day tomorrow either.*

Comment: Yes, either is used to compare when used in a sentence like your second one.

Answer (score 7):

As Kate Bunting says, grammatically it's positive, so it's "too" rather than "either". And there should be a comma between "today" and "too". However, it might just be me, but "It's a no-go today as well" feels more natural than "too". If nothing else, if the sentence is verbal, using "as well" avoids the listener having to spend the mental effort parsing "too" as meaning "too" rather than "to". Especially for foreign speakers, reducing ambiguity is good. There are subtle ways that native speakers mark "too" and "to" as different when speaking that foreign speakers often don't master. You can also say "Today is a no-go as well."

Comment: Is your last sentence meant to read "Today it's a no-go as well."?

Comment: @IlikedtheoldStackOverflow To me, "Today is a no-go as well" actually sounds more natural than "Today it's a no-go as well."

Comment: As a native Brit I would not bat an eyelid at "too" or "as well", both sound equally natural to me. I think the issue of confusing "to" and "too" is a bit of a red herring — while they are indeed homophones when placed last in a sentence (in most other contexts "to" uses its weak form /tə/ so there's no ambiguity there — so "I want to fish" and "I want two fish" are not pronounced the same), I don't think anyone would be confused in this case as there's no part of the sentence structure here that could possibly lead to a sentence-final "to". Use of "too" like this is common in British English.

Comment: @Muzer _To_ and _too_ **may** be homophones when stressed, but they may also not. To me (and my gut feeling says to most Brits, though I have no idea what the actual statistics are), “I know where we can go to” and “I know where we can go, too” are not homophonous: _to_ is /tʊ/ with a short, lax vowel, while _too_ is /tuː/ with a long, tense vowel.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet interesting, to me the only difference is that "too" receives heavy stress in that situation. The actual vowel quality is the same.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with what Kate Bunting and Acccumulation already said. Just wanted to add that an even more natural/informal way of stating the same idea (at least to me), would be something along the lines of "Another no-go today." or "Today is another no-go."

Comment: @Buzzyy New users can't leave comments, but regardless I think this **should** stand on its own as an answer, because it adds something that isn't found in any of the others: using "another." (This version sounds the most natural to me, out of all the options!)

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Ah, alright. I haven’t been on this website for a while